# SASS: Background image url and rails controller variables

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, assets

I need to show the profile picture of a user with the background-image property in a div class. The problem is, that the image-url and the asset-url are possible to call only from a scss file, and from a scss file, the @user variable is not visible. It says "undefined local variable or method `params'" when I try to access the user id. Couldn't find the answer in other topics.

```
background-image: image-url(<%= @user.avatar %>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your asset files are designed to be static in nature, especially when they've come down the asset pipeline with, precompiling, fingerprinting, and all. You can't have them change every time a different user logs in, because that would require a whole new precompiled, fingerprinted, and static asset.

Precompiling isn't a problem for you now because you're in the development environment, but will be an issue on production.

This is one of the rare scenarios where a `style` attribute is much more appropriate! Or, some in-page Javascript that would change the `style` attribute of all the elements that match your div's class/id/selector. You can utilize `asset_url` and/or `image_url` for this:

```
<img src="placeholder.gif" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_url(...)%>);" />
```

See the [AssetUrlHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) documentation, which is available on any Rails view!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll consider to make a change here, but still I'm interested to know is this possible. The problem with the second thing you said is that the sass properties image-url and asset-url can only be called from a .scss file and rails can't see the assets images with the regular "background: url". Could be that this can't be done at all.

Comment: @DR_ Sorry, I forgot to mention you can use `image_url` and `asset_url` in the views. I'll add it to my answer.